# My Bootcamp Windows system can't see my Mac files?

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I recently got a new MacBook Pro.  On my old computer I had a Bootcamp partition that runs Windows.  Everything installed on the new one fine, but I have a problem.  Why can't I see my Mac files from my Windows system?  On my old computer, I could see and move them while running the Windows system.  The Mac side has no problems accessing my Windows files.

Does anybody have a clue what I should change and on which system?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that with the latest version of OS X, the internal drive is converted to a Core Storage volume, rather than the simple HFS+ volume you presumably had on your old computer. Apple still hasn't rolled out support for this in many areas, Windows included. You won't be able to access your files directly anymore from within Windows until Apple gets around to implementing Core Storage in Windows, if they even have plans to do that. The only solution is to use an external drive or create another partition formatted as exFAT or FAT32 as a neutral location that can be accessed by both operating systems.

Comment: There are a number of utilities that make HFS+ volumes available to PCs, just not sure if they support core storage. Might be worth a quick Google for Paragon and MacDrive, to name a couple...

Comment: Another possibility would be to convert Core Storage back to normal storage. Core Storage is only needed if you use encryption or have a fusion drive.

Comment: You can't revert a drive back to HFS+ if it never was HFS+ in the first place, as in the case of a new computer. An unfortunate limitation of Core Storage.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you for taking the  time to help me. :)